# PostgreSQL adding a ' to the front and end of a string_agg output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a string that I can use with an IN statement in query. I currently have the query set up to output a string using the string_agg statement. The output looks something like xx','xy','xz',xb

The query looks something like

```
select string_agg( distinct column_row, ''',''') from new_table;
```

This outputs a string like above....... `xx', 'xy', 'xz', 'xb`. I would like to find a way to add one additional apostrophe to the beginning of the string and to the end of the string so it would look like `'xx', 'xy', 'xz', 'xb'`

Is there a way that I can use concat to add a ' to the beginning and end of the entire string so that the string will end up looking like `'xx','xy','xz',xb'`? Because I don't think I can use a string in an IN statement that doesn't have the apostrophe around all the characters.

Comment: Why not leave the aggregation out and use that statement directly inside the `IN` condition? `where x in (select ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 select '''' || col || '''' 
   from (select string_agg( distinct column_row, ''',''') col 
           from new_table) newt;
```

See it here on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf1fe/2)

Without the subquery will also work:

```
select '''' || string_agg( distinct col, ''',''') || '''' col 
  from test
```

See it here on [SQLFiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bf1fe/3)